# ASP.NET MVC Function that returns a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, function, model

I've a model that includes some data, but when the modelstate isn't valid it needs to fill up the model again. So i have to fill multiple times my model. So i would like to make a function that returns the model for me, so i can use it in my controller. How can i achieve this?

Thanks for reading.

I simply tried to make a public string.

This is my code:

```
    public string LaadGastenboek(int id)
    {
        Models.Berichten Gastenboek = new Models.Berichten();
        Models.Gastenboekmaken Gastenboekberichtmaken = new Models.Gastenboekmaken();

                int hoeveelzoudenermoetenzijn = id * 10 - 9;
                if (SQL.ReturnSingleINTResult("Select count(*) from Gastenboek where status = 1") >= hoeveelzoudenermoetenzijn)
                {
                    String Gastenboekunsorted = SQL.LaadGastenboek(hoeveelzoudenermoetenzijn);
                    // Gastenboek data -- Properties
                    int tellerhtml = 1;
                    int teller = 1;

                    // Array
                    if (Gastenboekunsorted != null)
                    {
                        string[] ArrayGastenboek = Gastenboekunsorted.Split('*');


                        // Split alles, 1 bericht is 3 data
                        for (int nummer = 0; ArrayGastenboek.Count() > nummer - 1; nummer++)
                        {
                            if (tellerhtml == 3)
                            {
                                Models.GastenBoekBerichtenModel item = new Models.GastenBoekBerichtenModel();
                                // Bereken het verschil, - 4 omdat hij begint te tellen bij 0
                                tellerhtml = teller - 4;
                                // Zet t/m 3 van arraygastenboek in de html code
                                // Bericht - Naam - Datum
                                item.Bericht = ArrayGastenboek[tellerhtml + 1];
                                item.Naam = ArrayGastenboek[tellerhtml + 2];
                                item.Datum = ArrayGastenboek[tellerhtml + 3];


                                Gastenboek.Add(item);

                                // Reset
                                tellerhtml = 0;
                            }
                            teller++;
                            tellerhtml++;



                        }
                    }
                }
                return (new Models.GastenboekOverall(Gastenboek, Gastenboekberichtmaken));
```

}

Comment: From your overview, you asks for a function that returns value. It doesn't sound like a real question.

Comment: The question is how i can modify my code that it returns a model.

Comment: instantiate an object of desired type and fill it's properties. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: First it is not nice to repopulate POSTed model after validation fails. You should respect users input and what he/she types in. You need to repopulate only things that are not on form as those things was not sended with request. If validation falis you should send back your action model parameter. I can think only about few things that can be repopulated like Lists (for selects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment: 
"The question is how i can modify my code that it returns a model."

I assume you want to modify your code to return model.

```
public Models.GastenboekOverall LaadGastenboek(int id)
{

    ... your code here ...

    return (new Models.GastenboekOverall(Gastenboek, Gastenboekberichtmaken));
}
```

In your controller to pass the model into view you can write, assuming your view consume model Models.GastenboekOverall.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return view (LaadGastenboek(someId));
 }
```